# Unable to Iterate Typescript Map object using .map() in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

If we have a Typescript `Map` object, how do we iterate it in order to render a number of items in React?

Using `.map` on the `Map` object causes Typescript to complain:

```
export function Foo() {

    type MyMap = Map<string, number>;
    const myMap: MyMap = new Map<string, number>();

    return (
        <div>
        {
            myMap.map(x => {  
                return (
                    <Foo key={x.id} score={x.score} />
                )
            })
        }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maps don't have a `.map` method. You also need to enclose JS expressions in `{}` delimiters when inside JSX in order to interpolate

Comment: Oops left our the curly brackets, updated question. For this case, how can the  Map object be converted to a type that have the `.map` method? Otherwise, is there another method that Map has that we can use for this?

Comment: Pick [one of the Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) iteration methods suitable for your needs. (`.map` isn't one of them)

Comment: Thanks, using `Array.from(myMap.entries())` allowed me to use the `.map()` method again. Is this a suggested way to do it?

Comment: Yes. For addtional context, `Array.from(myMap)` is equivalent to `Array.from(myMap.entries())`, which is also equivalent to `[...myMap]`.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript/TypeScript, [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is specific to arrays.

Consequently, an array must first be derived from `myMap`, in order for `Array.prototype.map` to be used on its contents.

This is often done using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), or more tersely using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

See below for a practical example.

```
export function Foo() {
  const myMap: MyMap = new Map<string, number>();

  return (
      <div>
        {[...myMap].map(([id, score]) => <Foo key={id} score={score} />)}
      </div>
  )
}
```